# MS Sql Server 2012 Must Declare Scalar Variable Exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and my database is MSSQL 2012. I have connected my Windows Forms C# application to the database. The issue that I am facing is that when I enter the search term and call the search method it says  `Must Declare Scalar Variable @id`
But I have already declared it. Here is my code

```
public void simInfo(long id,DataGridView dataGridView)
{
    try {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"//connect string here");
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand searchQuery = new SqlCommand(
            "select * from [Sim] where simOwnerId=@id",connection);

        searchQuery.Parameters.Add("@simOwnerId", id);

        using (SqlDataReader reader = searchQuery.ExecuteReader()) {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView.Refresh();
        }
    } catch (SqlException exception) {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see you using `"@simOwnerId"`

Comment: I also use  `searchQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("simOwnerId", id);`

Comment: This is a simple typographical error and after dealing it with a comment the question should be closed asap

Comment: what does it mean? @Zane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SqlCommand searchQuery = new SqlCommand("select * from [Sim] where simOwnerId=@id",connection);
```

You're using a parameter if `@id` here. But there is no existing `@id` parameter. Instead, you assigned the value of `id` to the parameter `"@simOwnerId"`.

```
searchQuery.Parameters.Add("@simOwnerId", id);
```

You can either change your query to

```
SqlCommand searchQuery = new SqlCommand("select * from [Sim] where simOwnerId=@simOwnerId",connection);
```

Or change the parameter name:

```
searchQuery.Parameters.Add("@id", id);
```

Comment: But In my other methods i am giving the columns parameter and it works like `SqlCommand searchQuery = new SqlCommand("select * from [Customer] where custId=@custID",connection);` and the parameters are `searchQuery.Parameters.Add("@custId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = custID ;`   @Invent

Comment: I am not saying you cannot use a parameter. When you use the parameter, you want to make sure you're using the correct parameter, though. In your code, you are not adding a parameter of `@id`, you are creating a parameter of `"@simOwnerId"` and trying to use it as `id`

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your SQL parameter to `@id`:

```
searchQuery.Parameters.Add("@id", id);
```

This is because in your query you have only parameter called `@id` and not `@simOwnerId`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
searchQuery.Parameters.Add("@id", id);
```

instead of

```
searchQuery.Parameters.Add("@simOwnerId", id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
searchQuery.Parameters.Add("@id", id);
```

instead of

```
searchQuery.Parameters.Add("@simOwnerId", id);
```

When you add a parameter, you have to writedown your parameter name, not the column name you filter.